# VbScript search for a specifc header and select the whole column

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am writing a VbScript to delete specific columns off an excel file dropped in via arguments. Row 1 of the excel files are the headers for the columns. Here's my current code to find a specific string among the headers.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo  "Drop excel files on this script"
Else
    objExcel.Visible = True
    objExcel.Workbooks.Add(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    Set FoundCell = objExcel.Range("A1:C1").Find("Sales Figures")

    '* Select the entire column of FoundCell and remove it

End If
```

My 1st issue is that i have to manually specify the range of headers (A1:C1) to search from. Is there any way to do it automatically (A1:X1) - where X is the last column in the excel sheet.

2nd, is how can i remove the entire column of FoundCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might help. You can use the [`UsedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) property of the Sheet object to select only cells that have data. This means you don't need to be explicit with column references.

`Cells(1)` restricts `Find()` to the first row of the UsedRange.

The bit I added at the end is just to close Excel down properly.

```vb
Option Explicit

dim objExcel, book, FoundCell
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo  "Drop excel files on this script"
Else
    objExcel.Visible = True
    set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    ' assume we're looking in the activesheet
    Set FoundCell = book.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Find("Sales Figures")

    if not IsNull(FoundCell) then
        '* Select the entire column of FoundCell and remove it
        book.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(FoundCell.Column).Delete
        ' book.SaveAs "removed.xlsx"
    end if

End If
' close up avoiding any "save changes?" dialog
for each book in objExcel.Workbooks
    book.saved = true
next
objExcel.quit
```